# How to migrate from VB.NET 2014 to VB.NET 2022?

Tags: vb.net

Moving and use new framework for old project at vs 2014 to vs 2022,

I'd like to move my project to VB.NET 2022 at Visual studio 2022 from vs 2014. I can directly open the old project with vs 2022 but the target framework just used the old one, the framework 4,5 at vs 2014, Any one can help?
Thank's at advance.

Comment: Is it any more difficult than changing the project properties to the desired framework version then fix any issues?  Is there something more to this question?  Or are you planning on moving to .Net7?

Comment: Am I missing something? There's no such thing as VS 2014 or VB 2014. It went 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017. Regardless, as suggested, you should simply be able to open the project and change the .NET Framework version in the project properties. While new versions of the VB language will have new features, what you're already using should almost certain work as is. You'll only be able to upgrade to .NET Framework 4.8.1 as the latest version. If you want to switch to .NET Core (.NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core) then you will need to do more. I believe Microsoft created a tool for that.

Comment: If you do want to migrate to .NET Core, you might start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/toc/migration-guide/).